# Grabbing an unordered index given a matching criteria

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame that is already filtered so the indices are not in order (i.e not from 0 - the end of my data frame). I have a column that is a 'bag of words'. This is simply a list of words. I know the word I am searching for. How can I find the index/indices that contain this word?
I tried using the '.index' function but I may not be using it correctly.

[Sample of DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rom8x.png)

Desired output would just be the index/indices of the entry/entries that contain the word I am looking for.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could provide a small sample of your dataframe, as well as your desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple hack for your case, considering bag column as a string rather than a list if you need to check only contains

```
df['word_flag'] = df['bag'].astype(str).str.contains('your-word-here')
```

If you specifically need the indices

```
df[df['word_flag'] == 1].index
```

Comment: @ravioliravioli If you find the answer helpful please accept it.

Comment: says I have to wait a few minutes, I will accept when I am able